# I have a problem generating random numbers (C)

Tags: c, arrays, function, random

My problem is that i cant figure how to make sure the rand function doesn't give the same number to 2 different cells and if it does how can i change it without getting to a number thats already in other cell.(the if(arr[j] != -1) is because i had other function that filled some cells with (-1) )

this is one version of how i tried to do it (all the // are leftovers from different tries)

```
void fillArr(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i,j=0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        while (arr[j] == arr[j + 2] &&j + 2<n)
        {
        //srand(time(NULL));
            if (arr[j] != -1)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {

                    arr[j] = rand() % (N - 1);
                    if (arr[j + 2] != -1)
                        arr[j + 2] = rand() % (N - 1);
                    //arr[i] = rand() % (N - 1)-rand()%(i-1);
                    srand(time(NULL));
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[j] = rand() % (N - i);
                    arr[j + 2] = rand() % (N - 1);
                    //arr[i] = rand() % (N - 1) - rand() % (i +1);
                    //srand(time(NULL));
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to go through already assigned numbers and see if the new `rand()` is a duplicate of already existing ones. Show the code you have now.

Comment: Because you have a problem of properly formulating the requirement. You need not to generate, but to *shuffle* numbers.

Comment: What is the *range* of the random numbers? Would `array[10]` be filled using the numbers 0..9?

Comment: This is not a C question if you are not showing a program that you need help with. If you are having problems developing an algorithm, tag the question as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why couldn't there be two equal numbers in an array of random numbers?

Anyway, if you want to prevent it, for every new value to be added in the array, iterate from the start and check if that number is already in. If so, generate a new number and check again.

Of course there should be enough unique numbers to be fit in the array (you can check this before you start), and in theory it could take forever, but in reality this does not happen.

Comment: Shuffling will be way more efficient unless the range of values is very large relative to the quantity of values desired.

Comment: @pjs indeed, but this is not clear from the code/description.

Answer (score 4):

You are not supposed to re-seed the PRNG in every loop iteration. You should do it once at the start of your program instead.

You'll produce a duplicate sequence of numbers as soon as you have multiple calls to `srand(time(NULL))` per second. Which doesn't seem to be unlikely in your code.

For reference:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand